# php change numbers with decimals from comma to dot

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

First of all I want to mention, because I think it's important, that I'm using my **own installation of apache-php-mysql** and my site is running on a virtualhost (FastCGI).

I have a code in cakephp to do a query in the database (oracle) and the quantities are returned with comma instead of dot to separate decimals (in oracle the numbers are with dot) for example 17.12345 is returned as 17,12345.

I´m convinced there has to be an instrucction on apache or php to change this, all answers i've read recommend to use str_replace but i don't think that's the right answer. **In XAMPP the same code works fine** and returns the numbers as saved in the database with dot so that's why i think i'm lacking for some instruction on the server side to fix this.

Comment: Maybe [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) helps?

Comment: I've tried that and didn't work, i forgot to mention it. i've set setlocale(LC_ALL,'es_SV.utf8'); in the controller and in the view and didn't make a difference.

i even read of using 'SetEnv   LC_ALL  es_SV.UTF-8' in the .htaccess to but nothing

Comment: `in the database (oracle) and the quantities are returned with comma` - this indicates that the problem is in the db config, or the driver/code used to communicate with it. Start e.g. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36823/glmec.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, don´t know if the best but works.

The [oracle plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/cakephp-oracle-driver) for Cakephp 3 triggers an ALTER SESSION query before every query we make, so i added this part **NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,'** to that alter session query that makes quantities dot separated.

This alter session is in *ROOT_CAKEPHP3\vendor\cakedc\cakephp-oracle-driver\src\Database\Driver\OracleBase.php* file, in the connect() function.

And this is the alter session query as final:

```
$config['init'][] = "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' 
              NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' 
              NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' 
              NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,'";
```

Comment: I think you're taking the right approach here but the manual says that `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` overrides `NLS_TERRITORY`. Are you sure your `NLS_TERRITORY` is set correctly for your formatting needs?